# Redirect / Failed to fetch error for service worker in Vue app hosted on Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am having difficulty debugging a failing service worker:

This is a single-page Vue app deployed to firebase, with the `firebase.json` file pasted below. The `service-worker.js` file is generated by the Vue build process.

When loading the web page over the hosted URL the console logs an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

The dev tools Application tab shows an error icon next to the service worker. It states that the service worker is redundant, and no client info is logged.

Looking through the network tab: the service worker attempts to use a `fetch` request to a file which returns a failed status. It then tries to load from the disk cache using a `fetchWrapper.mjs:111` initiator, which returns a `301` status code, and reattempts from the disk cache for a total of 20 requests.

[image: dev tool log]

I've made some attempts to resolve this by explicitly setting cache headers for `index.html` and `service-worker.js` to `no-cache`, as well as modifying the `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa` config: e.g. setting a navigation fallback and a fallback whitelist as was suggested by various discussions on `github` for fixing various errors with apps hosted on Firebase. But nothing seems to work thus far.

Any advice on how to debug would be appreciated.

`vue.config.js` configuration as of current attempts:

```
workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW',
    workboxOptions: {
      skipWaiting: true,
      clientsClaim: true,
      cleanupOutdatedCaches: true,
      offlineGoogleAnalytics: true,
      navigateFallback: '/index.html',
      navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__)/]
    }
```

The auto-generated `service-worker.js` as of current attempts:

```
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

importScripts(
  "/precache-manifest.2bc5009a43d646159ff19d2cc748dca9.js"
);

workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({prefix: "app-name"});

workbox.core.skipWaiting();

workbox.core.clientsClaim();

self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});

workbox.precaching.cleanupOutdatedCaches();
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute(workbox.precaching.getCacheKeyForURL("/index.html"), {
  whitelist: [/^\/[^\_]+\/?/],

});

workbox.googleAnalytics.initialize({});
```

`firebase.json` as of current attempts:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/index.html",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/service-worker.js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|webp|js|css|eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|woff2|font.css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=604800"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(json)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=604800"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": false
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that `cleanUrls` set to `true` is causing Firebase to redirect `index.html...` requests to `/`. Try removing that setting.

Comment: Thank you. I've already aborted use of the service worker but this may well be the source. Will report back if I later attempt to add it back in.